# PHP - Load variable page content

Tags: php, html

Apologies again, as I'm new to PHP so not fully sure how this works, but thought I'd ask.

I have a page called contract.php, which I'm hoping to use as a template so that when someone selects the contract they wish to view it goes to the contract.php and loads the content for that particular contract.

Hopefully I shouldn't need to create a page for every single contract, I was hoping that I could use the contract ID, so that when the navigate to the page it would show something like contracts.php?contractid=555 and then loads the contracts details for contractid 555, so this does this for each new contract that's listed.

The issue I'm having is, I'm not sure how best to go about it, or how to use this ?contractid='xxx' etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: If you append `?contractid=1234` to your URL, you get a variable `$GET['contractid']` in PHP with the value `1234`.

Comment: You'd run a simple `$_GET` query. However, we can't really answer correctly without any code.. Please add your code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$_GET manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

after reading the contract id from the get variable, you can search your DB for that contract and echo the specific data of this contract.

Also consider using [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) so that you can't easily see any contract by changing the url by yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch respective data from your database for each contract using the contract ID. Inside the **contracts.php**, check whether **contractid** variable is set and not empty, using `isset($_GET['contractid']) && !empty($_GET['contractid'])`. If it is true, then fetch respective data from the DB and display it to the user, in the template that you must have created.

Hope this helps. If you need more help then paste your code here.